# how to replace annotation with xml easily in Mybatis

Tags: mybatis

Recently I had a problem .I need to use mybatis in xml Way instead of annotation way . And I have a lot of   annotationed Mapper class .Do i hava an easy to to to this or I must write mapper.xml one by one .

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer as it is series of steps you need to follow for the transition. Follow this [example](http://sivalabs.in/2012/10/mybatis-tutorial-part1-crud-operations/) where everything is simple and self-explanatory right from scratch to get you started.